# How is best to parse json file with given structure

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I have a json file with following structure:

```
{
  "F:\\MyProject\\shopping\\images\\img_bags_clutch_10.jpg": [
    [
      "254, 254, 254",
      "215, 216, 217",
      "181, 181, 183",
      "240, 240, 241",
      "254, 254, 254",
      "254, 254, 254",
      "255, 255, 255",
      "255, 255, 255"
    ],
    [
      "190, 187, 183",
      "89, 85, 83",
      "98, 90, 81",
      "94, 92, 90",
      "118, 118, 121",
      "144, 144, 146",
      "253, 253, 253",
      "255, 255, 255"
    ],
    [
      "248, 247, 246",
      "213, 206, 193",
      "177, 176, 173",
      "63, 63, 63",
      "88, 89, 92",
      "165, 165, 166",
      "235, 235, 235",
      "254, 254, 254"
    ],
    [
      "255, 255, 255",
      "250, 250, 249",
      "227, 221, 208",
      "99, 99, 99",
      "98, 98, 98",
      "96, 94, 90",
      "92, 90, 87",
      "215, 216, 217"
    ],
    [
      "255, 255, 255",
      "255, 255, 255",
      "235, 235, 235",
      "93, 94, 96",
      "36, 38, 42",
      "43, 44, 47",
      "64, 66, 68",
      "158, 159, 161"
    ],
    [
      "255, 255, 255",
      "255, 255, 255",
      "255, 255, 255",
      "254, 254, 254",
      "199, 199, 199",
      "75, 77, 79",
      "132, 133, 132",
      "141, 140, 141"
    ],
    [
      "255, 255, 255",
      "255, 255, 255",
      "255, 255, 255",
      "255, 255, 255",
      "255, 255, 255",
      "220, 219, 218",
      "67, 65, 62",
      "137, 137, 137"
    ],
    [
      "255, 255, 255",
      "255, 255, 255",
      "255, 255, 255",
      "255, 255, 255",
      "255, 255, 255",
      "255, 255, 255",
      "215, 216, 217",
      "224, 224, 225"
    ]
  ],....
```

With the given pattern where key is some path to image, and value is serialized Color[,] (color matrix or 2-dimensional array of Color objects). Every entry, every key is described with this 8x8 array (values are RGB values for each block of the image).
I want this to store in Dictionary because of other application logic which uses Color[,] structure as input, produces some output and so on.
If I perform:

`var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Color[,]>>(json);`

Key elements are ok, but the value is always the first Color[,] structure.

Comment: It's not a 2 dimensional array of Colors. It's a 2 dimensional array of bytes.

Comment: I don't see it as a 2 dimensional array at all. I see it as `List<List<byte>>`

Comment: Haha, now I see that this file, which should represent serialized version of Dictionary<string, Color[,]> is not ok. So the way I wanted to retrieve values from file is OK, but the file itself is not ok. :)
So I could rephrase my question to:
How to properly serialize Dictionary<string, Color[,]> object and deserialize it later.